# What's a good workout routine to build muscle for skinny physique?

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding

I am 5"3 and I weigh 55 kgs. My goal is to build muscle.

My workout routine consists of the following:

- 15-20 tricep dips (3 sets)
- 20 wide arms push-ups (3-5 sets)
- 12-15 diamond push up (3 sets)
- 20-25 resistance band hammer curls (2-3 sets)
- 15-20 Overhead pulls with resistance band (2-3 sets)

I get about 2200-2500 cals from various sources and about 100 grams of protein every day.

What can I do to improve my workouts?

Comment: Is this the full extent of your workouts? When do you train legs and back? You know, the parts of the body that actually do the heavy lifting? If you want to build muscle, you gotta include everything.

Comment: @Alec. Thanks for pointing that out. Can you recommend some simple leg+ back workouts? I don't have any gym equipment save for resistance bands

Comment: It might help to read the other question, and then edit this one to a specific aspect of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I went from 170 lbs at 6’4” to 225 lbs in six months by doing 5 sets of barbell bench presses at 6 reps, 5 sets of seated barbell press behind the neck for six reps, 5 sets of barbell shrugs for 6 reps,, barbell curls for 5 sets at 6 reps, and 5 sets of barbell dead lifts for 6 reps. When you can do all the reps, go up in weight. The key is DON’T QUIT AND DON’T MISS A WORKOUT! The bigger issue is I drank four whole milk 50 gram protein shakes a day in addition to three good meals a day. And get at least eight hours of sleep a night. Bomb your body and eat like a horse to the point where you want to throw up. I would have included squats (5sets, 6 reps) if I’d had a way to protect me from getting stuck at the bottom.